# What are the different forms of nibbāna?

Tags: meditation, nirvana, five-hindrances

Often people refer to nibbāna with the cessation of all mental defilements.
However, does nibbāna also encompass 'momentary cooling off', for example when one engages in the various contemplations / mindfulness of breathing? If I, for example read suttas, I feel my mind is getting calmer and calmer, as if a heavy burden wanes.

Another 'momentary nibbāna' would probably be samādhi, where all hindrances lie dormant, right?

Comment: It's possible to have temporary events that may have flavour-tones of nibbana. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, even more subtle forms of cooling, like when medating on death, talking about virtue and generosity etc and in the grander scheme of things samadhi, jhana and final nibbana

Comment: The possibility of nibbana hinting at itself may occur but until one has reached nibbana one cannot know for certain if those prior experiences are nuances of enlightenment. Probably the best gauge to progress is noticing your degree of self-suffering diminish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This talk may help answer the question: [Nibbāna for Everyone](https://www.suanmokkh.org/books/84).

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. Extract the key points and put them in the answer.